# Data is not showing in react component render function

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I have the following code, which results nothing in render function:

```
Categories:[
{
_id:"MNN2Zc4M8XnavYdiH",
name:"Test Category",
status:1
}
];

Meteor.publish('findCategory', function(id){
    return Categories.find({_id:id});
});   


EditCategory = React.createClass({
  mixins:[ReactMeteorData],
  getMeteorData(){    
    return{
      Category:Categories.findOne({_id:this.props._id})
    }
  },
  render:function () {
    return(
      <div className=""><p>{this.data.Category.name}</p></div>
      )
  }
});
```

I want to display category name and other details , What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any errors? If you've defined all these in the same file then some of the code you have won't work.

Comment: try Categories.insert({your document here}); instead of Categories:[]; I don't think it creates a mongo collection

Comment: Categories are already in DB, initially it shows empty array when i console the 'this.data.Category' but after rendering the page it show an object of category data in render function that i required on initial loading.